# Sync Hyper-V Domain Controller to External Source for Time

Tags: windows, domain-controller, ntp

I cannot for the life of me get my Hyper-V PDC (2012 R2) to sync with an external time source. I have tried a number of configurations but in the end I can only get the `w32tm /query /source` command to show either `Local CMOS Clock` or `VM IC Time Synchronization Provider`

I've tried the following settings

#### Setup 1

- Time Syncronization Integration Service **enabled** on VM
- Run command `w32tm /config "/manualpeerlist: 0.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`
- Run command `net stop w32time && net start w32time`
- Run command `w32tm /resync /rediscover`

  - The above command successfully completes
- And `w32tm /query /source` shows `VM IC Time Synchronization Provider`

#### Setup 2

- Time Syncronization Integration Service **disabled** on VM
- Run command `w32tm /config "/manualpeerlist: 0.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`
- Run command `net stop w32time && net start w32time`
- Run command `w32tm /resync /rediscover`

  - The above command always fails with "The computer did not resync because no time data was available"
- And `w32tm /query /source` shows `Local CMOS Clock`

#### Setup 3

- Time Syncronization Integration Service **enabled** on VM
- Reg key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\VMICTimeProvider :Enabled:0`

  - This is supposed to disable the moment-to-moment synchronization of the VMICTimeProvider but still allow the service to perform on VM boot ([#6 Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/11/19/time-synchronization-in-hyper-v/))
- Run command `w32tm /config "/manualpeerlist: 0.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`
- Run command `net stop w32time && net start w32time`
- Run command `w32tm /resync /rediscover`

  - The above command always fails with "The computer did not resync because no time data was available"
- And `w32tm /query /source` shows `Local CMOS Clock`

What is the proper way to configure a Hyper-V PDC to correctly sync with an external source?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you disabled the Time Syncronization Integration Service in Setup 2 do you mean you unchecked that box in the properties of the VM? If so, then that's the correct procedure. Follow Setup 2 again and run the following commands on the DC from an elevated command prompt. Then reconfigure it as you did in Setup 2.

**net stop w32time**

**w32tm /unregister**

**w32tm /register**

**net start w32time**

Comment: I was really hoping this would work but I get the same result from w32tm /query /source = "Local CMOS Clock". I ran your four commands then then the w32tm /config command, the net stop/start command and finally the resync command

Comment: In the output of **W32tm /query /configuration** what is the Type listed as?